# How Do I Exclude a Particular Package Version with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

Right now, in my `build.sbt` I have a `libraryDependencies` that has something like

```
"some.package" %% "package-name" % "[1.4.2, 1.5["
```

as one of its elements.

Now let's say version 1.4.6 introduces some bug that's fixed in 1.4.7. How can I rewrite my dependency string to include all versions from 1.4.2 up to (non-inclusive) 1.5 except for version 1.4.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't try but Ivy's [version matchers](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/version-matchers.html) may help.

You can specify [Ivy configuration with matcher](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html):

```
 externalIvySettings()

 externalIvyFile(Def.setting(baseDirectory.value / "Ivy.xml"))
```

Settings.xml

```
<pattern-vm>
  <match revision="foo" pattern="..." matcher="..." />
</pattern-vm>
```

Ivy.xml

```
<dependency org="acme" name="tool" rev="foo()" />
```